# alertView textFieldAtIndex nil then if-condition passes anyway

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I have a short question is someone wants +15 rep. :D

```
//This returns nothing, nil, or "" (no quotes)
NSLog(@"alert view text field : %@",[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);

//In theory this if-condition should NOT pass
if([alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil || [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != @"")
{
    NSLog(@"IF!");
}
//in other words, "else" should run
else {
    NSLog(@"ELSE");
}
```

Instead I get this as output:

[29929:fb03]alert view text field :

[29929:fb03]IF!

EIDT: ok, as answered by the questions, i put in

```
if(!([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString:@""]) || !([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString: nil]) || !([alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil))
```

but the if STILL passes and it shouldn't. I dont get it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use isEqualToString method to compare strings

!([alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text  isEqualToString:@""])

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings with `==`. If you do that, you're comparing the pointers of two string instances, which is unlikely to be what you want. Instead, try:

```
if([alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil ||
   ![[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString:@""])
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare `NSStrings` in Objective-C using `isEqualToString` comparator like so -

`if(![[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString:@""]) 
        NSLog(@"IF!");`

Answer (score 0):

Change your operator to `&&` instead of `||`:

```
//This returns nothing, nil, or "" (no quotes)
NSLog(@"alert view text field : %@",[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);

//In theory this if-condition should NOT pass
if([alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil && [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != @"")
{
    NSLog(@"IF!");
}
//in other words, "else" should run
else {
    NSLog(@"ELSE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem here

```
[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil
```

You are comparing a NSString to nil.  Think about it, what are you trying to compare? Are you trying to see if the NSString contains an empty string link so @"" ? or are you trying to see if the NSString object points to nil.

You can see this here:

```
NSString *test = @"something in here";
if (test == nil) {
    NSLog(@"String pointer is nil");
}
else
    // It will pass here
    NSLog(@"String pointer is not nill");
```

So in your case above, the *if* condition passes, because the pointer to that object is *not* nil. It actually exists.